# Is this possible to configure Single Sign On between Salesforce Sandbox and Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, single-sign-on

I am trying to configure Single Sign On between Salesforce Sandbox and Marketing Cloud Organization following [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-ExactTarget).

I receive error message

> Provided federation ID could not be found, or the account or user is
>   not properly configured for SSO.

I have checkbox **Allow Single Sign-On** checked on Marketing Cloud User Id and **Federation ID** is set on my Marketing Cloud User Id to the same value as **Federation Id** on Salesforce Sandbox User.

Key Management feature of ExactTarget is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I receive the same error, under the following situation.  I have single sign on enabled.  I attempt to open Marketing Cloud from within Salesforce.

Marketing Cloud asks for me to activate the browser.  Once I click send, the error occurs.

To resolve this, there is an option in Admin | Security Settings.  **In the Single Sign-On Settings section, set a value of Yes for "Do not require Identity Validation for SSO Logins"**

Now when logging in, the Activation and error does not occur and I can log in successfully.

Comment: I don't remember how did we solve that problem... it was more than a half a year before... I guess I will mark your answer as accepted, actually I no longer have access to marketing cloud instance anymore to test if this is working now...